# Sorting double with Counting Sort

Tags: c#, sorting

I'm trying to sort double digits with counting sort. Tried to convert all doubles to integer but for some reason nothing happens. My code that sorts intergers.

```
public static void CountingSort(DataArray items) {
    // O(1)
    int max = items[0];

    // O(N)
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++) {
        if (items[i] > max) {
            max = items[i];
        }
    }   

    // Space complexity O(N+K)
    int[] counts = new int[max + 1];

    // O(N)
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++) {
        counts[items[i]]++;
    }
    // O(N+K)
    int j = 0;
    int c = items.Length - 1;
    int current, previous;
    for (int i = 0; i < counts.Length; i++) {
    while (counts[i] > 0) {
        while (c > j) {
            if (items[c] == i) {
            current = items[c];
            while (c != j)
        {
        previous = items[c - 1];
        items.Swap(c, current, previous);
        c--;
        }
    }
    c--;
    }
    j++;
    counts[i]--;
    c = items.Length - 1;
    }
    }
}
```

Is it even possible to sort double digits with counting sort?

Answer (score -1):

To sort a `double` array, use

```
double[] doubleArray = new double[5] { 8.1, 10.2, 2.5, 6.7, 3.3 };
doubleArray  = Array.Sort(doubleArray);
```

After that, use a loop for count.